# fields of content type show as sidebar menu in drupal

Tags: drupal, show, sidebar, drupal-content-types

I am newbie in drupal I learned how to create content types, but I need do it:
I have the content type **project** with *fields location, arquitect, images, contact, saler, etc* each field is text with google maps reference, the profile of arquitect responsable, imageg of project, info of contact, saler profile respectively I need to show this info in this way. How Can I do this? I am usin **Drupal 8**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by installing and setting 'Views' module: 
https://www.drupal.org/project/views, then to create new view with block display that will show fields only for current node ID of your specific node type by using contextual filter in advanced section when editing views:

You can setup your view block like this:

[image: You can setup your view block like this]

Add in contextual filters node nid:

[image: Add in contextual filters node nid]

For this contextual filter, select provide default value of type PHP code and set to retrieve it through arg(1):

[image: For this contextual filter, select provide default value of type PHP code and set to retrieve it through arg(1)]

When you finish setup your view, your block will appear under blocks, so you can assign it to region you want to, i.e. sidebar.

If you want to, you can restrict visibility for specific content type.

For drupal 8 it is content -> ID, then select "Provide Default Value" when the filter value is not available, and under type select "Content ID from URL"

Under section advanced, add new contextual filter

[image: Under section advanced, add new contextual filter]

Choose Content: ID

[image: Choose Content: ID]

Choose provide default value and Content ID from url

[image: Choose provide default value and Content ID from url]

Comment: Iam using drupal 8 I can't found the second part when the filter is not available type php code, what do you mean? contextual filters -> content:Nid what is this nid?

Comment: In drupal 8, views is a core module, so you don't need to upload it, you just need to enable it. 
Nid is Node's ID, every node has unique ID.

Comment: but in drupal 8 Advanced->contextual filters->add shows a dialogo add contextual filters and in the search box I type Nid but it dont apears

Comment: @DavidUntama, For drupal 8 it is just content -> ID, then select "Provide Default Value" when the filter value is not available, and under type select "Content ID from URL"

Comment: sorry I try but I cant reach it

Comment: I edited answer, please check again, since there should be offered Content: ID under contextual filters

Comment: to be able to select fields in contextual filters , u need to add them first to the view field list